# Doubt on precession

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, precession

So we are studying rotation of rigid body. Our teacher talked about precession but not in much detail

It got me thinking so if we have axis of axis of rotation then

1. how many such axis of axis of .......of body can be there
2. if the answer is many can't we ultimately represent any motion as sum of such motion

Sorry if it's nonsense as it is coming from just physics enthusiast and not a scholar or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is only one axis of rotation. This is because angular velocity can be described as a vector quantity. It is impossible to have two axes at once without having the particle exist in two places at once.

http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_11.html

2. Since angular momentum is conserved, $L = MR^2w = M(r_x^2+r_y^2+r_z^2)w$.

Answer (score -2):

Refer to the bible of physics :http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_11.html